# How to add an SSL certificate (ca-cert) to node.js environment variables in order to connect to Digital Ocean Postgres Managed Database?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ssl, digital-ocean, node-postgres

I am currently using node-postgres to create my pool.  This is my current code:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')

const pgPool = new Pool({
  user: process.env.PGUSER,
  password: process.env.PGPASSWORD,
  host: process.env.PGHOST,
  database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
  port: process.env.PGPORT,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    // Would like to add line below
    // ca: process.env.CACERT,
},
})
```

I found another post where they read in the cert using 'fs' which can be seen below.

```
const config = {
database: 'database-name',
host: 'host-or-ip',
user: 'username',
password: 'password',
port: 1234,
// this object will be passed to the TLSSocket constructor
ssl: {
  ca: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/digitalOcean/certificate.crt').toString()
 }
}
```

I am unable to do that as I am using git to deploy my application. Specifically Digital Oceans new App Platform. I have attempted reaching out to them with no success.  I would prefer not to commit my certificate in my source control.  I see a lot of posts of people suggesting to set

```
ssl : { rejectUnauthorized: false}
```

That is not the approach I want to take.  My code does work with that but I want it to be secure.

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Alright I finally was able to figure it out.  I think the issue was multiline and just unfamiliarity with dotenv for my local developing environment.

I was able to get it all working with my code like this. It also worked with the fs.readFileSync() but I didn't want to commit that to my source control.

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const fs = require('fs')

const pgPool = new Pool({
user: process.env.PGUSER,
password: process.env.PGPASSWORD,
host: process.env.PGHOST,
database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
port: process.env.PGPORT,
ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    // ca: fs.readFileSync(
    //     `${process.cwd()}/cert/ca-certificate.crt`.toString()
    // ),
    ca: process.env.CA_CERT,
},
})
.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('connected to the database!')
})
.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('error connecting to database ', err)
})
```

Now in my config.env I had to make it look like this:

```
CA_CERT="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nVALUES HERE WITH NO SPACES AND A \n 
AFTER EACH LINE\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
```

I had to keep it as a single line string to have it work.  But I was finally to connect with

```
{rejectUnauthorized:true}
```

For the digital ocean app platform environment variable,  I copied everything including the double quotes and pasted it in there.  Seems to work great.  I do not think you will be able to have this setting set to true with their $7 development database though.  I had to upgrade to the managed one in order to find any CA cert to download.

Comment: While using app platform I had to manually upload the app_spec.yaml for this to work but if finally did

Comment: @Alejandro, I followed this method to a T but I'm still getting::  Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain. I am deploying on digital ocean app platform and the logs is showing me the certificate is present with all the \n but DB still won't connect

Comment: Is there any other way to this, my app is nestJs + Postgres + typeorm

Comment: I can't remember what I did to make it work but try uploading the app_spec.yaml manually. You can try setting the CA_CERT to a value with double quotes and without them if that doesn't work. Also make sure you have the variable available with the scope set to RUN_TIME. Mine is set to secret so I can't actually confirm which of the options work. I can however confirm I only had to do it once. I am using a Production Managed DB from DO, and the project also works with NestJS, Postgres and TypeORM.

Comment: Mah man, this was exactly what I was looking for. How is this not in the docs??