# Trying to connect to production Pgsql DB but got connection time out (0x0000274C/10060)

Tags: laravel, postgresql, digital-ocean, table-plus, digital-ocean-apps

Note: My database works because I am able to migrate and query from within the application.

So I've setup my application and database on digital ocean's new "App" feature. And now I am trying to connect to the production database but I'm getting connection timeout error. Below are the details I inputed, but maybe I am missing my SSL cert ? If yes, how do I go about getting this ? Because I believe digital ocean automatically setup the SSL for me..

Database : postgresql
Tool used to connect : TablePlus

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

My site is SSL'ed
[image]

Checked directly on DO, and there's no certificate stored on my account
[image]

Comment: I don't think SSL would stop you here, as the error would be you are missing SSL cert or something similar, you can't connect to it directly, so I would assume you did not open ports or similar, but I have no idea how Apps works.

Answer (score 0):

So after a few days I gave up and swap to using Droplets. I feel Apps Platform is cool for quick prototypes but I don't have much control in what I want can do in it. I don't think I could even run sudo in the console when I tried.

Here are a few other links I ran through that may or may not help others that was in similar situation if you were using a dev database on digital ocean. And also my support tickets solutions that I received.

**Links**

1. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/cannot-connect-with-dev-database-due-to-ssl-issue?answer=67513
2. https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/databases/postgresql/how-to/connect
3. [How to add an SSL certificate (ca-cert) to node.js environment variables in order to connect to Digital Ocean Postgres Managed Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66501428/how-to-add-an-ssl-certificate-ca-cert-to-node-js-environment-variables-in-orde)

**DO Support Replied**

> I understand that you are trying to connect to the database with an
> SSL certificate. Firstly, I want to let you know that you have
> attached the dev database to your app "mysite" and not the production
> database. However, you should be able to add the following env
> variable to store the SSL certificate:
>
> KEYS: CA_CERT VALUES: ${mysitedb.CA_CERT}
>
> Once you add the above env variable then you should be able to use the
> "CA_CERT" variable to fetch the SSL certificate in your app.
> Additionally, you can view the SSL certificate by running the
> following command in the console:
>
> echo $CA_CERT

> Thanks for getting back to us. This output would be intended. To use
> the contents of that cert you would need to save the env variable to a
> file or convert it from string using a method within your application.
> You can then specify that file in your configuration and use the
> certificate in your connection to the database.
>
> An example of how to do this can be found here:
> [How to add an SSL certificate (ca-cert) to node.js environment variables in order to connect to Digital Ocean Postgres Managed Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66501428/how-to-add-an-ssl-certificate-ca-cert-to-node-js-environment-variables-in-orde)
>
> Let us know if you have any questions.

> Thank you for getting back to us!
>
> From the screenshot, I see you are using the incorrect port number
> 5432. You have to use port number 25060 to connect to the database.
>
> Regarding the SSL certificate, one thing to note here is that the
> database is managed by DigitalOcean and it is not possible to generate
> clients key (private key) and certificate (public key) via cloud
> panel. That is the reason, you will need to generate those on your
> local machine or from whichever client you plan to establish a
> connection to the database.
>
> Here is an example of how to use SSL on a client like Navicat, you
> will need to download or have OpenSSL installed on your operating
> system which you will use to generate Client Key File and Client
> Certificate File which will be referred to as private and public keys
> respectively
>
> You need the below three files to connect
>
> - Client Key File
> - Client Certificate File
> - CA Certificate File
>
> https://www2.navicat.com/manual/online_manual/en/navicat/linux_manual/SSLSettings.html
>
> As a guide to establishing a connection
>
> - Generate Client Key File and Client Certificate File from your client or the local machine
> - Copy the certificate from app console to any .crt file and pass that file to connect to database.
>
> Here is how to use the OpenSSL to generate the Client Key File and
> Client Certificate File:
> https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO27347.html
>
> openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout client-key.pem -out
> client-cert.pem -days 3650 -nodes -subj '/CN=localhost'
>
> For the Client Key File, Client Certificate, and CA Certificate choose
> the directory location you saved them and click on "Test" button in
> your client to test the connection.
>
> Please let us know if you have any additional questions, and have a
> wonderful day!